# Strong partition property + DC + existence of non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, determinacy

It was mentioned after Theorem 30.27 in Kanamori's Higher Infinite that Woodin constructed a model of $DC$ + there exists unboundedly many many $\kappa<\Theta$ such that $\kappa \to (\kappa)^\kappa_{\alpha} \ \forall \alpha<\kappa$ and there exists a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$. In particular, this model is not a model of $AD$.

What is the reference of this? Or even better for those who know the proof, what does the proof look like? Thanks!

Comment: You start with determinacy in $L(\mathbb R)$ and add an ultrafilter by a forcing that adds no sets of ordinals, such as $\mathcal P(\omega)/\mathrm{Fin}$.

Comment: The reference you want is "A barren extension" by Henle, Mathias and Woodin. I'll try to post a brief answer later today.

Comment: To add to the comment of @Andrés, since $\mathcal P(\omega)/\rm fin$ is also $\sigma$-closed, it preserves $\sf DC$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key reference for this is

> [MR0799042 (87d:03141)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=799042). Henle, J. M.; Mathias, A. R. D.; Woodin, W. Hugh. *[A barren extension](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0075312)*. In **Methods in mathematical logic (Caracas, 1983)**, C. A. Di Prisco, editor, 195–207, Lecture Notes in Math., 1130, Springer, Berlin, 1985.

There, Henle, Mathias, and Woodin start with $L(\mathbb R)$ under the assumption of determinacy (and [$\mathsf{DC}$](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=736611)), and force with $\mathcal P(\omega)/\mathrm{Fin}$; they refer to the resulting model as "the Hausdorff extension".

They use $\mathsf{ZF}+\omega\to(\omega)^\omega$ to prove that the Hausdorff extension is *barren*, meaning that every map from an ordinal into the ground model was already in the ground model. They also show (under $\mathsf{AD}+V=L(\mathbb R)$) that all strong partition cardinals below $\Theta$ are preserved in the extension. Easily, the extension also preserves $\mathsf{DC}$.

On the other hand, the forcing adds a Ramsey ultrafilter on $\omega$ (in particular,  unboundedly many strong partition cardinals below $\Theta$ is not enough to ensure all sets all reals are Lebesgue measurable).

Comment: (Let me know if you need a copy of the Henle-Mathias-Woodin paper.)

Comment: Great! Thanks! I managed to find its internet existence. This is helpful!